# How do you set DISABLE_NEWLINE_AUTO_RETURN when using SetConsoleMode?

Tags: c, winapi, windows-console

When I try something like this;

```
SetConsoleMode(hScreen, ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT | ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING | DISABLE_NEWLINE_AUTO_RETURN);
```

it fails; the return value is zero and the mode isn't changed.

If, however, I do this:

```
SetConsoleMode(hScreen, ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT | ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING);
```

Then it works.

How do you set DISABLE_NEWLINE_AUTO_RETURN?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running on?  Looks like some of those flags were only introduced very recently.

Comment: I'm using the latest windows 10 version.

Comment: Build 1511, or the latest preview build?  Anniversary edition is out next week IIRC, it might be worth upgrading and seeing if that makes any difference.

Comment: I'm using build 1511. It could be not available just yet. I assumed the two new options would be available together and one of them does work.

Comment: Unfortunately the only copy of the page in the Wayback Machine is from March and includes neither option, so we don't know whether they were added at the same time or not.  *Usually* the documentation explicitly lists what version of Windows is required for each option, looks like somebody at Microsoft dropped the ball.  What error code do you get?

Comment: I get error code 87 "the parameter is incorrect"

Comment: Error 87 strongly suggests an unsupported flag.  Although it might just be an unsupported *combination* of flags.  There's only four other flags, so perhaps it would be worth trying all 16 combinations to see whether any of them work?

Comment: I haven't systematically tried all combinations but I have tried most.